# Use NSOrderedSet from CoreData with UITableView

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift3, tableview, nsorderedset

I'm trying to use an NSOrderSet in CoreData to populate my tableview. I have been able to read the count number of the NSOrderedSet, but can't seem to access the individual attributes of the Entity that makes up the NSOrderedSet.

I'm using this for the numberOrRows

```
 return (currentStatement.history?.count)!
```

Where currentStatement represents an Entity in CoreData and History is another Entity that has a toMany relationship with the Statement Entity.

I'm trying to access the History > date attribute like this inside the CellForRowAt method.

```
 print("\(currentStatement.history!.object(at: indexPath.row).date) saved date") // Looking for the date data that was saved
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: It changes it to this:   `cell.date.text = (currentStatement.history!.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).date` it then says this: "Can not assign value of type UILabel!! to type String? "

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the actual issue you are running into, this should work:

```
let history = currentStatement.history?.object(at: indexPath.row) as! History
print("\(history.date) saved date")
```